# LazyInitializationException in Spring service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

I'm developing an application in Spring 3.0.5 and Hibernate 3.6.2, and currently i'm working in a JSON controller, but i have this exception and i can't understand why is happening. I've checked previously in SO and Google, but this problem is quite strange. So here is my code:

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/props", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody 
List<Property> getJsonProps(String id) {        
    if(id==null)return null;
    Device dev = deviceService.getDispositivo(Long.parseLong(id));
    List<Property> props = deviceService.listProperties(dev, 10);
    return props;
}
```

Device Service

```
@Service("manageDevices")
@Transactional(readOnly=true,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ManageDevicesImpl implements ManageDevices {

private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
private DevicesDAO devicesDAO; 


    public List<Property> listProperties(Device dev, Integer qty) {
    List<Property> props =  devicesDAO.pickProperties(dev, qty);
    return props; 
    }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository("devicesDAO")
public class DevicesDAOImpl implements DevicesDAO {
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()); 

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public List<Property> pickProperties(Device dev, Integer qty) {
    if(qty >= 0){           
        log.debug("Open? "+ sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().isOpen());
        log.debug("Tx Active? " + sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive());
        List<Property> props = dev.getProperties();
        if(props != null){
            if(props.size() >= qty)
                return props.subList(0, qty-1);
            else
                return props;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

The exception occurs in the pickProperties function (DAO Layer), at the line where i try to load the properties (getProperties). In the logs, there is an open session and transaction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post the exact exception you got?

You're in *a* transaction at the `dev.getProperties()` line, but not the transaction where `dev` was loaded. You either need to reattach it, or arrange for `dev.getProperties()` to be called while you're still in the transaction that loaded it, or move the transactional boundary up so that both calls are in the same transaction, or change the Hibernate configuration so that `properties` isn't lazy loaded, or change the code that loads `dev` so that it fetches `properties` in HQL.

Which of those options will apply to you depends on your situation, but I'd start with the last one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The exception being thrown was org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException, i don't post the whole stack trace because your post clarified some concepts, and as a result i'll modify the logic in the service method, to ensure that all will be done inside the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your transaction is created after the `Device dev` is read. Try reading/rereading it within the transaction to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, certainly it was a design fault, calling the getProperties method inside the loading method of "device" it works just fine, I'll modify the service method to do all the fetching in one single transaction.